# Initializing correct union member based on compile time evaluation

Tags: c, initialization, unions, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I want to initialize different union member depending if a macro expression is a constant or a variable.

So far I've found GCC extension `__builtin_constant_p()` which evaluates an expression and returns 1 if it is a constant and 0 otherwise. Which is exactly what I need. However I have yet to found a way how to initialize different union members based on this information.

Below is the code example:

```
#define TOKEN 10

typedef union 
{
    void* pv_variable;
    int literal;
} foo_t;

foo_t test_array[] =
{
    {.literal = 500},
    {.pv_variable = NULL}

    // Below doesnt work. How to make it work??
    //
    // {(TOKEN == 10) ? (.literal) : (.pv_variable) = 10},
    // {__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_constant_p(TOKEN), .literal = 10, .pv_variable = NULL)},
    // {. ## __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_constant_p(TOKEN), literal, pv_variable) = 10},
};
```

EDIT:
Clarification on what I want to accomplish is detailed below.

```
#define INIT_UNION(val) /* TODO: */
#define SOME_VARIABLE some_variable
#define SOME_CONSTANT 10

int some_variable = 20;

typedef union 
{
    void* pv_variable;
    int literal;
} foo_t;

foo_t test_array[] =
{
    INIT_UNION(SOME_CONSTANT), /* should produce: {.literal = 10} */
    INIT_UNION(SOME_VARIABLE)  /* should produce: {.pv_variable = &some_variable} */
};
```

Comment: Why not a good old `#if` ?

Comment: @Mat Because TOKEN is actually a macros variable argument.

Comment: Would adding a comma after the 2nd literal initialiser help? Me? I'd go with the KISS principle and follow @Mat...

Comment: If `#if` doesn't work then your example doesn't reflect your actual requirements (missing the 'reproducible' part of [mre]) – you should consider to modify it such that `#if` won't work here either.

Comment: @Aconcagua How the hell would an #if work? I need to check if an expression is a constant or a variable AT COMPILE TIME.

Comment: Not really an imagination of what you *actually* try to do – just the feeling that we're talking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: @Aconcagua Clarified.

Comment: Hm... And how do you decide later on which union member actually is the active one? How would you correctly access the pointer if it is of type `void`? You'd need to adjust every such code at compile time as well.

Comment: @Aconcagua I store the type along with the value.

Comment: From your comment at an answer: "`_some_variable` is not always the same. It comes from a variable argument list._" Please [edit] your question and show what you mean. A list of two variables suffices.

Comment: C++ (since C++11) has the appropriate means to do what you want to achieve here – not even needing any platform/compiler specific stuff – see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dcGoqYrTP). Now if you moved just the initialisation to C++ and left all the rest in C (some ideas for are sketched in the link already) – could that be an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea was pretty close:

```
#define TOKEN 10

typedef union foo_u
{
    void* pv_variable;
    int literal;
} foo_t;

#define INIT_FOO_T(val) (__builtin_constant_p(val) ? (foo_t) {.literal = val} : (foo_t) {.pv_variable = val})

foo_t test_array[] =
{
    {.literal = 500},
    {.pv_variable = NULL},
    INIT_FOO_T(TOKEN)
};
```

Unfortunately you can use `#if` inside a `#define`, so this is the only way.

Maybe instead of:

```
#define INIT_FOO_T(val) (__builtin_constant_p(val) ? (foo_t) {.literal = val}
```

you mean:

```
#define INIT_FOO_T(val) (__builtin_constant_p(val) ? (foo_t) {.literal = &val}
```

this would make more sense but requires a different approach (it won't work anymore).

EDIT: you want the second case

```
#if __builtin_constant_p(TOKEN)
foo_t test_array[] =
{
    {.literal = 500},
    {.pv_variable = NULL},
#if __builtin_constant_p(TOKEN)
    {.literal = TOKEN},
#else
    {.pv_variable = &TOKEN},
#endif
};
```

Unfortunately I don't know how you can build a macro to do this for you.

Comment: I further clarified the question.

Comment: I see, this makes it a lot more complicated, because now you need a macro decision instead of just a normal compile time decision.

Comment: I can make yours kind of work with:
<code>#define INIT_FOO_T(val) (__builtin_constant_p(val) ? (foo_t) {.literal = (int)val} : (foo_t) {.pv_variable = (void*)val})</code>

And then using<code>INIT_FOO_T(100)</code> for literals and <code>INIT_FOO_T(&some_variable)</code> for variables.

Comment: That would work, but it also defeats the sense of the problem. Why not use `.pv_variable = &some_variable` in the first place when you already know.

Comment: some_variable is not always the same. It comes from a variable argument list.

Comment: This is why it would defeat the sense of the problem. I tried to point that out. I think what you are trying to do is impossible duo to how the preprocessor works.